# Why don't I see the different li markups inside my page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx, next.js

Here is my code

```
export default function Search({ res }) {
    var arr = Object.entries(res)
    console.log(arr)
    return (
      <div>
        Here's the result :
        <ol>
            {arr.map((value, index) => {
                <li key={index}>{value.title}</li>
            })}
        </ol>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  export async function getServerSideProps({ params }) {
    const { id } = params;
  
    const req = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:4000/reddit/${id}`
    );
    const res = await req.json();
  
    return {
      props: { res } // will be passed to the page component as props
    };
  }
```

At this point :

```
console.log(arr)
```

This line prints me a beautiful array with 100 subarrays because the fetching was good from the API...

Data looks like this array : `[["0", {title: "I like eating", textValue: "Yes, I do"}], ["1", {title: "I like dirinking", textValue: "Yes, I do"}]]`

But in the page I have only the markup

with nothing inside

I don't succeed to know why...

Comment: Please show us what the values inside `arr` look like. Also, when you say you have "only the markup", do you mean that the page is showing actual HTML tags to the person viewing the page?

Comment: Is the data structure like this or something like that? ```[{id:1,title:'t1'},{id:2,title:'t2'}]```

Comment: With only the markup, I mean that the page displayed in the client side returns only `<div>Here's the result :<ol></ol></div>`

Comment: Data looks like this array : [["0", {title: "I like eating", textValue: "Yes, I do"}], ["1", {title: "I like dirinking", textValue: "Yes, I do"}]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the map function, also you should see some error on your console about that:
`Expected to return a value in arrow function. (array-callback-return)`

```
return (
  <div>
    Here's the result :
    <ol>
        {arr.map((value, index) => ( //<--return items
            <li key={index}>{value.title}</li>
        ))}
    </ol>
  </div>
);
```